# how to encode string with unicode characters python

Tags: python

I have a sql statement: select 'ó' from dual;
after running fetchall for this statement I get the following string.'\xc2\xbf' in python.

How do I get the original text based on the string returned? any ideas?

thanks!

Update: It turns out that the fetchall might be converting the  'ó' to an inverted questionmark(the \xc2\xbf). any ideas why that is. I'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
??
```

Comment: if u want to see it,if that is meant by get,then `print '\xc2\xbfn'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode is what you're looking for.